# ng2-chart: this.chart is undefined sometimes and won't display data

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-charts

I have been using ng2-charts version 2.4.3 to display charts on my website. A lot of my charts work great! However, I have 3 charts that periodically will not display or error in the console. When debugging `this.chart` is undefined when trying to initialize the chart. How do I make sure the charts initialize 100% of the time not 60% of the time.

Here's the code where I initialize the chart.

HTML

```
  <div style="display: block" *ngIf="lineChartData.length > 0">
    <canvas baseChart
            height="300" width="400"
            [datasets]="lineChartData"
            [labels]="lineChartLabels"
            [options]="lineChartOptions"
            [legend]="lineChartLegend"
            [chartType]="lineChartType"
            [colors]="chartColors"
            [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
    </canvas>
  </div>
```

TS

`@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective, {static: true}) chart: BaseChartDirective;`

```
  console.log(this.chart, this.lineChartData)
  if (this.chart && this.chart.chart) {
    this.chart.chart.data.datasets = this.lineChartData;
    this.chart.chart.data.labels = this.lineChartLabels;
    this.chart.update()
  }
```

This will work like 60% of the time but sometimes nothing with work since the chart is undefined.

Comment: `@ViewChild` will only set the value after the `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle is called. Before that, it will be `undefined`

Comment: I have that code snipped in a helper function that gets call on ngAfterViewInit and ngOnChanges.

Comment: ```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.chart, 'after')
    this.generateChartData();
  }

```

The log here is still null

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually not related to the data. When the responsive flag is true, and the width and height are set in the canvas it causes issues. In order to fix it, I simply updated the HTML to this.

```
 <div style="display: block; height: 400px" *ngIf="lineChartData.length > 0">
<canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="lineChartData"
        [labels]="lineChartLabels"
        [options]="lineChartOptions"
        [legend]="lineChartLegend"
        [chartType]="lineChartType"
        [colors]="chartColors"
        [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
</canvas> <div>
```